# browser issue in php?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

i design one form for registration of users.

in that i use  tag
in  i use align="center"

```
<fieldset style="width:618.233px;" align="center">
```

but now problem is that in IE it run successfully.But in firefox it cant accept "align=center".
it just display form bydefault(means left align)

i cant user  tag because form get ugly look.
what should i do?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: When I browse a php site, I have an issue with it  ;P

Comment: @leppie You have an issue with HTML, dude

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Not, I have an issue with PHP, a very personal one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give margin : auto;

Answer (score 0):

There is no align property to the fieldset tag in html. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_fieldset.asp).

```
<fieldset style="width:618.233px; text-align:center;" />
```

Comment: hey dude but it works on IE.
anyway i got solution from boss.

Comment: There are standards, which all browsers try to work towards, and there are non-standard proprietary features which should be avoided because they *don't* work everywhere.

Comment: It might work in IE but it's still invalid HTML. Well at least your problem is solved. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Align text in the center with CSS `text-align` property, not the whole fieldset.
2. Give fixed width to the fieldset (you already have `width:618.233px;`) and add this CSS properties: `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` or simply `margin: 0 auto;`